# How can I get the type of property with template t4 in order to format datetime in jqgrid?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, jqgrid, t4

I'm trying to format the date used with jqgrid.

I'm using the MVC scaffolding with T4.

There is one part in the T4 template like this

```
jQuery("#ajaxGrid").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GridData")',
        datatype: "json",
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "<#= Model.PrimaryKeyName #>" },
        colNames: [<#= string.Join(", ", properties.Select(prop => "'" + prop.Name + "'")) #>],
        colModel: [
            <#= string.Join(", \r\n         ", properties.Select(prop =>
                string.Format("{{ name: '{0}', editable: true, sortable: true, hidden: {1}, align: {2} {3}}}", prop.Name, prop.Name == Model.PrimaryKeyName ? "true" : "false", "left", prop.Type.ToString() == "DateTime" ? "sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'm/d/Y h:i AmPm'": "")
            )) #>
        ],
        rowNum: 5,
        pager: '#ajaxGridPager',
        width: '850',
        height: '15em'
    });
```

prop.Type.ToString() == "DateTime" ? "sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'm/d/Y h:i AmPm'": "" doesn't work.

I want to format the date if the field is DateTime as in the webpage I see /Date(1315968717587)/ and I want to change the T4 template to automatically generate it correctly for future entities.

How can I accomplish that?
Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

**EDIT**

I've read that I can reference Microsoft.VisualBasic and use

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(prop)
```

But it is returning CodeProperty2. I can't figure it out how to get the real type.
I tried with

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.TypeName(prop).Type
```

and then it says: 
error CS1061: Compiling transformation: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Type' and no extension method 'Type' accepting a first ar
gument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So it knows it's string but ToString() returns CodeProperty2 as well.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I didn't have any other answer yet, I'm fixing it looking at the name of the property. If it contains the string "Date", I format it as Date, but I'd like to avoid that, since I don't want to tie the name of the property jqgrid, I mean, one should be able to name the property whatever one want and it should keep working and showing it as date.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
prop.Type.GetType() == typeof (System.DateTime) 
   ?  "sorttype: 'date', datefmt: 'm/d/Y h:i AmPm'"
   :  ""
```

Comment: No, prop.Type.GetType() outputs System.__ComObject

Comment: Hmm do you know what interfaces this Com object implements? Perhaps there are ways to query what type it represent?

Comment: Don't know, Anyway I can find it out?